# Extended classes and undefined Variables - PHP

Tags: php

Square and Rectangle are classes that extends abstract class ShapesClass, defining their own Area methods.

```
    abstract class ShapesClass
    {
        // Force Extending class to define this method
        abstract public function Area();
    }

class Square extends ShapesClass
{
    private $side = 0;

    function __construct($n)
    {       
        $side = $n;     
    }

    function Area()
    {
        echo $side * $side;
    }
}

class Rectangle extends ShapesClass
{
    var $length = 0;
    var $width = 0;

    function __construct($a,$b)
    {
        $length = $a;
        $width = $b;
    }

    function Area()
    {
        echo $length * $width;
    }
}

$listShapes = array();
$listShapes[0] = new Square(3);
$listShapes[1] = new Rectangle(3,4);

$listShapes[0]->Area();
$listShapes[1]->Area();
```

I get undefined variable errors on side, length and width.
Doesn't these three variables have default values and are also set by the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code whenever we create variables for any class we can call them inside methods with the class reference only i.e. $this

Also, in php we can define the variables with var there are public, protected and private keywords to define any variable.

So, you can update your code with the below code

```
abstract class ShapesClass
{
    // Force Extending class to define this method
    abstract public function Area();
}

class Square extends ShapesClass

{
    private $side = 0;

    function __construct($n)
    {       
        $this->side = $n;     
    }

    function Area()
    {
    echo $this->side * $this->side;
    }
}

class Rectangle extends ShapesClass {
    private $length = 0;
    private $width = 0;

    function __construct($a,$b)
    {
        $this->length = $a;
        $this->width = $b;
    }

     function Area()
     {
         echo $this->length * $this->width;
     }
}

$listShapes = array();
$listShapes[0] = new Square(3);
$listShapes[1] = new Rectangle(3,4);

$listShapes[0]->Area();
$listShapes[1]->Area();
```

Answer (score 6):

You actually want to refer to them as `$this->foo`

```
function __construct($a,$b)
{
    $this->length = $a;
    $this->width = $b;
}
```

Basically `$foo` acts like a local, variable, scoped to current method. `$this->foo` acts like a instance variable, which is available anywhere in the class.